# Fastest LSTM training in CPU-only (no-GPU) setting

Tags: neural-networks, software, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Training more or less sophisticated RNNs (e.g. LSTM) takes ages in CPU-only setting.

I've tried Lasagne-over-Theano, Keras-over-TF and torch-rnn implementations of character-level language models (shakespeare.txt / nietzsche.txt) and they are terribly slow.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: (You may be interested in this SE proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93761/software-comparisons?referrer=eXJdSXLAwPITV26ETy7aVA2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a question for CV but I recognise the type of issue this presents for modelling.

Why no-GPU? Unfortunately this restriction limits the software you'll have at your disposal. GPU based training seems standard in the literature now.

Next, if you're determined to use a CPU: if theano plays nice with cython that's a quick route to use theano infrastructure for training with fast implementation of numerical/string tasks.

There are also DNN frameworks in Julia e.g. Mocha.jl.  Generally you can get into the nuts and bolts with Julia and I think this extends to [strings](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/strings/), e.g. it has a distinct `Char` object unlike python for character level manipulation. Using multiple CPU cores is also easy.